# Ransack with Ruby 2.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ransack

I'm trying to use Ransack on RoR app.
https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack

Unfortunately latest ransack only support ruby 2.6+. Mine is 2.5.8.
So what should I do? Any available version is there on Ransack?

Comment: You can lock to the latest version that supports Ruby ~ 2.5, which is `ransack 2.4.1`. Latest version is `2.4.2` - https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/commit/87a1697f34ce4d25f7be155243918e833526a442

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an older version, namely `2.4.1`.

If you look on `rubygems.org`, you can quickly see the minimum required ruby version for each version of the gem:

- [`2.4.2` requires ruby `>= 2.6`](https://rubygems.org/gems/ransack/versions/2.4.2)
- [`2.4.1` requires ruby `>= 2.3`](https://rubygems.org/gems/ransack/versions/2.4.1)

However, you shouldn't even ordinarily need to check this manually!! If you run `bundler update ransack` on a project, it will **automatically** fetch the latest compatible version of the gem, given all your other dependencies.